# The meaning for a domain name which has a valid DNS response but does not exist in zone file?

Tags: dns, tld, zone

I know my question is not related to programming, but i thought maybe someone be able to help me. 
I have a list of domain names for different TLDs. I also have the zone files for my TLDs but some of my domain names does not exist in the zone file. I checked the DNS value for my domain names and some of them have valid DNS A response.
I think the zone file for a TLD should include all domain names registered by that TLD. IS that correct? if yes, what is the meaning of having DNS response for a domain name but that domain name does not exist in the zone file?

For example I checked the zone file for ews.com.link TLD from icann and it does not include ews.com.link domain name, when I am sending a DNS query or dig for ews.com.link, I am getting below response:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> ews.com.link
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 43251
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 6, ADDITIONAL: 15

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ews.com.link.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ews.com.link.       900 IN  A   101.132.249.163

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.link.       900 IN  NS  ns3.myhostadmin.net.
com.link.       900 IN  NS  ns1.myhostadmin.net.
com.link.       900 IN  NS  ns4.myhostadmin.net.
com.link.       900 IN  NS  ns6.myhostadmin.net.
com.link.       900 IN  NS  ns2.myhostadmin.net.
com.link.       900 IN  NS  ns5.myhostadmin.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.myhostadmin.net.    2790    IN  A   113.17.175.150
ns1.myhostadmin.net.    2790    IN  A   183.131.155.224
ns1.myhostadmin.net.    2790    IN  A   211.149.230.100
ns2.myhostadmin.net.    2790    IN  A   113.17.175.200
ns2.myhostadmin.net.    2790    IN  A   120.52.19.214
ns3.myhostadmin.net.    2790    IN  A   113.17.175.150
ns3.myhostadmin.net.    2790    IN  A   183.131.155.224
ns3.myhostadmin.net.    2790    IN  A   211.149.230.100
ns4.myhostadmin.net.    2790    IN  A   120.52.19.214
ns4.myhostadmin.net.    2790    IN  A   113.17.175.200
ns5.myhostadmin.net.    2790    IN  A   211.149.230.100
ns5.myhostadmin.net.    2790    IN  A   113.17.175.150
ns5.myhostadmin.net.    2790    IN  A   183.131.155.224
ns6.myhostadmin.net.    2790    IN  A   120.52.19.214
ns6.myhostadmin.net.    2790    IN  A   113.17.175.200

;; Query time: 356 msec
;; SERVER: 128.119.240.1#53(128.119.240.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Aug 15 13:51:21 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 409
```

The same results for below domain names which I check them in their tld zone file :

```
newd.com.limited
neqs.com.center
nesw.com.house
nsws.com.academy
bbc.com.cards
hews.com.camp
amh.com.pub
smg.com.zone
dmh.com.fail
hews.com.town
jews.com.photos
shm.com.toys
newws.com.boutique
ne3s.com.africa
nrws.com.game
nrws.com.africa
naws.com.tienda
nwes.com.cheap
niws.com.kitchen
amh.com.toys
newe.com.shoes
newx.com.koeln
smg.com.toys
```

Comment: "*I think the zone file for a TLD should include all domain names registered by that TLD*" yes but with some exceptions: a domain with NS records (not delegated) will not be published by registry, nor will a domain with an EPP `clientHold` or `serverHold` status or equivalent.

Comment: *having DNS response for a domain name but that domain name does not exist in the zone file?* this is impossible to parse/understand, especially with a true example without obfuscation. Your local recursive nameserver may override some replies and clain to be authoritative for some records, see `dnsmasq` features for example. And your question is not related to programming, so offtopic here.

Comment: thank you @PatrickMevzek, do you have a link or reference for understanding how dns zone files work? I mean a reference which explains the cases and all of the reasons for not having a domain name in a zone file which we have dns response for that?

Comment: do you have a referenc for this:"a domain with NS records (not delegated) will not be published by registry, nor will a domain with an EPP clientHold or serverHold status or equivalent." I need to cite to that in my report. thank you

Comment: I have many examples which I get a response for DNS A query but that domain name does not exist in zone file. (About your this answer: this is impossible to parse/understand, especially with a true example without obfuscation)

Comment: "*which explains the cases and all of the reasons for not having a domain name in a zone file*" it is pretty much in my earlier comment but like I said earlier also it is impossible to be thorough if we keep being generic... you show no details, not event the TLDs concerned, and no examples of your observations like some non obfuscacted  `dig` queries and replies.

Comment: *I have many examples*  great! show them and then we can discuss some specific cases (but again we are offtopic here)

Comment: As for "*do you have a referenc for this:*" I am pretty much describing the standard way of DNS functions in broad terms in my comment, so RFC1034/1035 on how the DNS work and https://icann.org/epp for an introduction otherwise STD69 for all EPP details and specifically §2.3 of RFC5731... Again having examples would make the explanation clearer.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I edited my question and added some example to it. Can you please check it?

Comment: Please explain what "I checked the zone file for ews.com.link TLD from icann" means? ICANN, at most, will give you the list of TLDs, so you will find `.link` in it, nothing more as expected. Then `com.link` is one domain name among the `.link` TLD, you can do a whois on it. If you download the .LINK zonefile it will be in it. Then `ews.com.link` is just a label under `com.link` and you would have seen it in `com.link` zonefile if its owner gave it to you. (it is a wildcard `*.com.link` in fact). There is nothing extraordinary in your observation but you may have wrong assumptions about the DNS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments and edits you may have some wrong assumptions about how the DNS works and what is a zonefile and what is in it. So my answer below will be from what I understand you are viewing as a problem. RFC 1034/1035 are the basis on how the DNS works, but they are old and technical documents so not really good introduction/tutorial on the subjects. Wikipedia articles on DNS may be better starters.

The DNS works as a tree (except that we reference it more as roots, because the root aka `.` is at the top and then we discuss things below it). Each node is administratively responsible of everything below it, and delegates part of the tree below to other nodes.

This has been done for many reasons but one of the target was in fact to go away from the global `hosts` file where you had at that time (pre DNS) a list in it of all possible names and their IP.
Now with the DNS you do not have a central list of all existing names for both technical and non technical reasons.

Technically, since you can have wildcards in various zones (which is the case in your examples, see below), the list of names is infinite or at least so big that you can not build it. Of course, its rate of change would also be difficult to follow.

Non technically, as I said each node is responsible for what it does... and may decide that the list of domain names (sub nodes) it has below it is note to be given publicly (which may or may not be for good reasons, and may or may not be easily circumvented like with DNSSEC NSEC enumeration, but that is not the point here).

So let us go back with your core assertion on an example we can now dissect:

> I checked the zone file for ews.com.link TLD from icann and it does not include ews.com.link domain name, when I am sending a DNS query or dig for ews.com.link, I am getting below response

First, when you say ICANN you are probably more talking about IANA (as ICANN by itself has no technical operations in the day to day DNS). IANA handles the root zone, `.`, also called the apex. In summary, it basically contains the list of all currently delegated TLDs.
This zonefile is public, and can be retrieved in various ways: downloading by HTTP/FTP from IANA website, or just doing an `AXFR` DNS request to one of the DNS root servers allowing it, like `f.root-servers.net`.

So if you get it, and search in it, it is absolutely normal that you do not find `ews.com.link` in it. But you will find `.link` which is a current valid TLD delegated to some registry.

You can check using whois targeting IANA whois server too:

```
$ whois -h whois.iana.org link
% IANA WHOIS server
% for more information on IANA, visit http://www.iana.org
% This query returned 1 object

domain:       LINK

organisation: Uniregistry, Corp.

[..]

whois:        whois.uniregistry.net

status:       ACTIVE
remarks:      Registration information: http://uniregistry.link

created:      2014-01-09
changed:      2018-06-06
source:       IANA
```

Now you can recursively do the same thing: `.LINK` is a gTLD so under the ICANN contracts. They mandate it (the `.LINK` registry) to publish its zonefile. This requirement will be the same for all gTLDs, and at the opposite side, in ccTLDs case it is rare to be able to get their zonefiles.

So if you go through th appropriate procedures you will get the `.LINK` zonefile. Again, as expected you will not see `ews.com.link` in it, because the registry has delegated `com.link` (which is a normal domain name under `.LINK` like any other, do not be fooled by first label being `com` this changes nothing on the explanation) to some registrant that decided to buy it at some point. And then use it any why it wants.

You can check in the DNS on registry authoritative nameservers or use registry whois server to check that this `com.link` domain name has been registered and delegated in the DNS:

```
$ whois -h whois.uniregistry.net com.link
Domain Name: com.link
Registry Domain ID: DO_fd33bffce176f0124de4523031e7b404-UR
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.west263.com
Registrar URL: west263.com
Updated Date: 2017-10-12T09:33:41.832Z
Creation Date: 2017-07-26T20:26:32.723Z
Registry Expiry Date: 2020-07-26T20:26:32.723Z
Registrar: Chengdu West Dimension Digital Technology Co., LTD
```

and

```
$ dig @NS1.UNIREGISTRY.NET com.link NS +nodnssec +norecurse +nocookie +noall +auth

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> @NS1.UNIREGISTRY.NET com.link NS +nodnssec +norecurse +nocookie +noall +auth
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
com.link.       900 IN NS ns4.myhostadmin.net.
com.link.       900 IN NS ns6.myhostadmin.net.
com.link.       900 IN NS ns5.myhostadmin.net.
com.link.       900 IN NS ns3.myhostadmin.net.
com.link.       900 IN NS ns2.myhostadmin.net.
com.link.       900 IN NS ns1.myhostadmin.net.
```

So this domain name is delegated to *myhostadmin*. The organisation behind it could, technically, offer anyone to download its zonefile (and/or allow AXFR requests) for anyone to know all about domain names below it, like your `ews.com.link`. However that does not happen for the reasons outlined at the beginning, and because this entity has no reason to do it.

However you can easily check that the given name exists (so is indeed listed, in some way, in the zonefile, even if you do not have access to it) by querying the responsible nameservers:

```
$ dig @ns1.myhostadmin.net. ews.com.link +nodnssec +norecurse +nocookie +noall +ans

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> @ns1.myhostadmin.net. ews.com.link +nodnssec +norecurse +nocookie +noall +ans
; (3 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
ews.com.link.       900 IN A 101.132.249.163
```

In fact, with some curiosity, you will discover that there is a wildcard record. You can easily see that by replacing `ews` by any random string and getting back the exact same result (which shows that the complete list of domain names can not be in the zonefile, as this wildcard makes the server generate the reply for any name you are querying it with), or checking specifically for the wildcard record:

```
$ dig @ns1.myhostadmin.net. *.com.link +nodnssec +norecurse +nocookie +noall +ans

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> @ns1.myhostadmin.net. *.com.link +nodnssec +norecurse +nocookie +noall +ans
; (3 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
*.com.link.     900 IN A 101.132.249.163
```

Using a wildcard record is a common feature when you need to have nameservers to reply to many names, not necessarily known in advance and that can change often, when you do not want to reconfigure your nameservers each name. Technically using a wildcard is not without drawbacks, and needs at least to be careful but other than that it is a core DNS feature.

So this all explains why `ews.com.link` exists in the DNS (if you query for it you get an IPv4 address back thanks to the `A` record) but you will not find it, as is in any zonefile, first because it does not exist, as expected, in the `.` (root) or `com` (TLD), nor in the `com.link` zonefile, even if you would have access to it, just because it is a wildcard so the specific `ews` name is not even written anywhere.

All the other names you give are probably in the exact same case based on their common `something.COM.something` format. I hope that with the above explanations you could just recheck any of them you like and be prepared to understand the case more with all these explanations.

Again, about

> The same results for below domain names which I check them in their tld zone file

for all the names you list you will find `com.TLD` in the `TLD` zonefile, but not `whatever.com.TLD` as this has nothing to do in the `TLD` zonefile, for any TLD.